# want to show only 2 names at a time from list and click on button next 2 names comes but there is a bug

Tags: html, css, knockout.js

I want to show only first 2 things which are present in an array instead of all and then b y clicking on button next 2 names comes up till the last, but the code which I am trying is not working. I am giving the code please tell the bug. Can you help me in correcting the code of knoctout js .

In Javascript

```
function viewModel()
    {
        this.displayCount = ko.observable(2);
        this.readMore = function () 
        {
             this.displayCount(this.displayCount() + 2);
        };

        this.WhoElseAttends = ko.observableArray([]);
        for (var i = 0; i < WhoElseAttends().length; i++)
        {
            this.WhoElseAttends.push({ data-bind="text:FirstName", data-bind="text:LastName", data-bind="text:Company" });
        }   
    }
  ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

In HTML

```
<div class="slide">
    <button type="button" data-bind="click: readMore, visible: displayCount() < WhoElseAttends().length">Read More</button>
        <ul data-bind="foreach: WhoElseAttends.slice(0, displayCount())">
            <li>
                <span data-bind="text:FirstName"></span>
                <span data-bind="text:LastName"></span>,
                <span data-bind="text:Company"></span>
          </li>
      </ul>                  
   <span data-bind="if: WhoElseAttends.length <0">No Attendees</span>                    
</div>
```

Comment: Please make a fiddle or something.

Comment: here data is coming from server but I dont think that fiddle takes that

Comment: I guess some json testing data will do?

Comment: could you please help me ? I will be thankful to you

Comment: @user3756425: Working on it...

Comment: @user3756425: Initially need to show first two items of the array and click of the button remaining all items in the array should listed or only two two items should get listed on each click

Comment: then next 2 items comes , then cclick on button again next 2 comes like that

Comment: understood and thanks alot my friend. I am shivani

Comment: ya i hv posted but i dont get appropriate answer

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things wrong with how your javascript is working.  to add new items to an observableArray it need to be a valid Javascript object.

```
this.WhoElseAttends.push({ data-bind="text:FirstName", data-bind="text:LastName", data-bind="text:Company" });
```

is not valid.  it need to change to something like

```
 this.WhoElseAttends.push({
            FirstName: 'First Name',
            LastName: 'Last Name' ,
            Company: 'My Company'
        });
```

Also be very careful with using `this` as it can change depending on the context.  one of the conventions in javascript is to immediately assign `this` to a variable. something like

```
var ViewModel = function(){
    var self = this;
    self.someProperty = ko.observable();

};
```

I think this is what your basically after

http://jsfiddle.net/M3dgk/2/

Paging: http://jsfiddle.net/M3dgk/3/

Comment: hmm actually there are names in the server suppose 10000 names are there and when the page is loaded suppose 100 names are seen and upon that there is a button , by clicking on that button next 100 comes up  means from 101-200 and till 10000. will this code works for that , I will be thankful if you kindly gv ur tym to me on this code

Comment: By the sound of it you are trying to do paging. All this code will do is reveal the number of records specified in the display count.  So to make it the next 100 records change the 2 to 100. but it wont hide the previous 100.

Comment: can you do that of hiding

Comment: have a look at the updated fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/M3dgk/3/